# Mean value theorem for $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{3-x^{2}}{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the following function
$$f(x)=\frac{3-x^{2}}{x-2}$$
does the Mean value theorem applies to if in the interval $[1,3]$?

Since $f$ is not defined for $x=2$ then $f$ is continuous and differentiable in $[1,3]-\{2\}$. So, the theorem is valid. But I can't find a number $c\in(1,3)$ such that
$$f'(c)=-2$$

Comment: The mean value theorem will hold individually in $[1,2),(2,3]$

Comment: $[1,3]-\{2\}$ is not closed interval...

Comment: @Sil It is not even an interval at all!

Comment: Where do you get the $-2$ from? In other words, for which $a,b \in [1,3], a< b$ do you have $f(b)-f(a)=-2(b-a)$?

Comment: @Surb $-2=(f(3)-f(1))/(3-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) doesn't apply. $f$ is not continuous on $[1,3]$ nor differentiable on $(1,3)$ as it is not defined at $2$!

Comment: In my opinion, we shouldn't say that the MVT does not hold *because* $f$ is not continuous. There are discontinuous functions for which the MVT holds. Continuity is a sufficient condition, no?

Comment: I'm not saying that MVT does not hold. I'm saying that **it doesn't apply** because the hypothesis for applying it are not satisfied. You can't apply a theorem whose hypothesis are not satisfied. The conclusion of the theorem can hold though, but that's a different story. The OP question is : *does the Mean value theorem applies*?. Answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

The mean value theorem will **apply** individually in $[1,2),(2,3]$ but not over $[1,3]-\{2\}$ since it is not an interval.

But the conditions of the theorem are **sufficient** conditions, that is to say, the conclusion of the theorem may **hold** even for discontinuous functions/domains. In short, the conclusion may **hold** in cases where MVT does not **apply**. For example, it holds for $f(x)=1,x\in[-1,1]-\{0\}$ but MVT doesn't apply.

You can see that the MVT does not **hold** in our case either since for $x\in(1,3)-\{2\}$,$$f'(x)=\frac{(3-x)(x-1)}{(x-2)^2}>0$$so there is no $c\in(1,3)-\{2\}$ for which $f'(c)=-2=\frac{f(3)-f(1)}{3-1}.$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of the OP *does the Mean value theorem applies to if in the interval $[1,3]$?* Which is no.

Comment: I have made some edits and distinguished between a theorem "holding" and "applying" for clarity. The OP should not be left with the notion that a theorem not applying implies that the theorem does not hold.

Comment: To be even more precise, the **theorem may hold** should be replaced with the **conclusion of the theorem may hold**.